# How can I have ls follow the content of a directory like tail -f does on a file

Tags: command-line, bash, ls, tail, coreutils

I want to basically continuously update the file list of a directory similar to how tail does with the `-f` flag on a file.

is there any reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using the `watch` command with `ls`:

```
$ watch ls -l
```

`watch` will repeatedly execute the given command at regular (2 second) intervals, which can be configured through command-line options.

Comment: thank you. its still useful for me from the future. 2020 here :)

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, use *inotify-tools*:

```
inotifywait -qme create,attrib,move,delete mydir |
while read -r; do
    clear
    ls -l mydir
done
```

Somewhat different:

```
inotifywait -qme create,attrib,move,delete --format '%w%f' mydir |
while read -r file; do
    ls -ld "$file"
done
```